# Python: how to make legend after twinx

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(x,y1,'go-')
ax1.plot(x,y2,'ro-')
ax1.plot(x,y3,'g*--')
ax1.plot(x,y4,'r*--')
ax2.plot(x,y5,'bo-')
ax2.plot(x,y6,'b*--')

ax1.set_xlabel('cluster size')
ax1.set_ylabel('number of nodes', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('error rate', color='b')
```

I want to plot 6 curves as above. There are two Y-axis.
I don't know how to make legend for these 6 curves.
What I want to get is like

```
legend([y1,y2,y3,y4],['A','B','C','D'])
legend([y5,Y6],['e','f'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a label for each `plot()` statement you have. For example:

```
ax1.plot(x,y1,'go-', label='A')
ax1.plot(x,y2,'ro-', label='B')
ax1.plot(x,y3,'g*--', label='C')
ax1.plot(x,y4,'r*--', label='D')
```

Then, calling

```
ax1.legend()
```

will automatically create the legend you want, because calling `legend()` with no arguments fetches handlers and their respective labels automatically.

If you want separate legends, you can also specify different locations for them via the `loc` argument. Check the [guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) for more details.